# Updating Sql , through a view via wpf and ef

Tags: c#, wpf, ado.net-entity-data-model

**Background**

- I am starting a series of simple screens to display and update info in our ERP database.
- I have worked through the wpf controls and understand the need for Observable Collections and after reading around on Entity Framework I understand the advantages of it sitting on top of ADO.net compared to the basic SQL methods and Datatables I am more comfortable with due to my SQL experience.
- When I tried EF when I was first started working with Data CRUD screens I struggled to  get the Observable Collections I needed, but having read this walk through last night ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574514.aspx)  and seen the notes for VS 2010 to edit EF code to get Observable Collections I think I want to try EF again.

**Question**

- My Data screen needs present information which has be combined from five tables and a couple of sub views to be meaningful to the user.
- Included in the dataview is a simple Y/N flag which comes from one of the five Datatables.
- Can the user update the Y/N flag through the view mapped to EF, displayed in WPF datagrid ?
- Or do I have to map all the base Datatables and sub views and recreate the view and Data Context in EF to allow the update to work?

If it is the latter does any one know of any tutorials or walk through I can use on my test development to try EF please

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user can update a field via the view mapped to EF, however it is a little bit more complicated.

For a single table mapped to EF, the update is done by EF automatically, for a view mapped to EF you need to define the update function in the mapping details.

[image]

The function would be in form of an SQL stored procedure mapped to EF.

Comment: Ahhhh that makes more sense....I am in hospital at mo but when I get home I will try. Is the update method in SQL via ADO.NET?

Comment: I don't think that ADO .NET is relevant here as EF does all the work under the hood.